# Connection problem, site-to-site, VYOS

Tags: vpn, ipsec, vyos

I'm having problem with a site-to-site. I think I have the basic setup working and I want to confirm that the tunnel is up and working. Here is what I have:

```
vyos@<vpnxy>:~$ show vpn ipsec sa
Peer ID / IP                            Local ID / IP
------------                            -------------
<other endpoint>                        172.31.16.102

    Tunnel  State  Bytes Out/In   Encrypt  Hash    NAT-T  A-Time  L-Time  Proto
    ------  -----  -------------  -------  ----    -----  ------  ------  -----
    1       up     0.0/0.0        3des     sha1    yes    1289    3600    all


vyos@<vpnxy>:~$
```

This seems to indicate to me that the tunnel is up, only no traffic is flowing through it which I guess means that we aren't looking for a problem in VPN setup but rather in routing or natting somewhere?

Is this a safe conclusion or can there still be VPN problems that causes the lack of traffic and if so how can  Ieffectively troubleshoot them?